# Is it possible to use _.range with multiple steps?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am curious if you can use `_.range` with multiple steps.

For example, if I wanted all the numbers `< 50 divisible by 2 and 7` could I do
 `_.range(0,50,(2,7))` or something along those lines?

If not - best practices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`_.range` does not allow that possibility, you would have to use another function like `_.filter`, to extract the values that you want

```
_.filter( _.range (0, 50), (value) => { return value % 2 == 0 && value % 7 == 0;  })
```